# how to put hidden action in table?

Tags: jquery, button, action, hidden

i have two button inside my form, i set them inside table:

```
<table id="status">
        <tr>
             <td>
                     <p align="center"><button id="accept">Accept</button></p>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <td>
                      <p align="center"><button id="reject">Reject</button></p>
                 </td>
             </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

i have the hidden action like below:

```
<input name="action" value="newinputdata" type="hidden">
```

i want this code can manage two submit button inside form.
or are you have any idea that i can use both of buttons for submiting the form?

Comment: you want to insert it with jquery? and  how will you submit both even if you insert it. Please explain your question a little more.

Comment: @sAc:can you understand what i mean for now?

Comment: What i see is that you have two input type buttons but later you are talking about two submit buttons. So still your question isn't that clear to me. I hope someone understands that and answers that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit a form with jQuery:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: is this code can make one form submitting by two submit buttons?

Comment: Yes. Use as many buttons as you want. It's a Javascript form submit, so it doesn't make any difference which button triggers the method call.